# Cannot connect to data warehouse using ODBC connection

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

I'm trying to connect to my work data warehouse directly in R using an ODBC connection.

I've installed the RODBC package.

I'm then creating the connection:

```
ch <- odbcConnect("DSN", "username", "pass")
```

I get the following error (I've obscured my credentials):

> Warning messages:
>   1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DSN;UID=UID;PWD=PWD") :
>     [RODBC] ERROR: state IM014, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
>   2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DSN;UID=UID;PWD=PWD") :
>     ODBC connection failed

I'm using a 64 bit version  of R and R Studio.

I attempt to connect to the same warehouse using an ODBC connection within tableau and the exact same credentials and it works perfectly and let's me pull back tables.

Any ideas why it's not working within R with this package?

Comment: Do you have the 32-bit ODBC driver also installed? R might be getting that confused with the 64-bit version

Comment: Using the data source administrator, I look under drivers for SQL Server and i Can see 32 in the filename. Hopefully this is the correct way to check. If this is the issue, why does Tableau not have a problem connecting?

Comment: Tableau may be a bit smarter than R. Try using `odbcDriverConnect` and give it a specific driver name.

Comment: Sorry i'm a bit new to this. What driver should I be using? I'm assuming a 64bit one but I don't think I have one.